# How to change URL dynamically with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new at Jquery and Javascript. I was trying to modify [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_dom_attr_set) example at: w3schools to change to url from the initial: *www.w3schools.com* to the second one at: *www.w3schools.com/jquery* and back again to the initial one when click on the button (as many times as desired), but I can not figure out how to do it. Please, include all the code in the answer, it will be easier. Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#w3s").attr("href", "https://www.w3schools.com/jquery");
});
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <a href="https://www.w3schools.com" id="w3s">
            W3Schools.com
        </a>
    </p>
    <button>
        Change href Value
    </button>
    <p>
        Mouse over the link (or click on it) to see that the value of the href attribute has changed.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First Hover the Link You Will See... www.w3school.com .... after click on button link change ... you can check it

Comment: @Miguel By answer seemed to of been downvoted for no reason (*perhaps by bots*), anyways it answers your question. The other questions are just copying the code you gave and placing it in an answer.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FGOSUXX5HUOG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Hover the Link You Will See... `www.w3school.com` .... after click on `button` link change ... you can check it with `hover` the Link. Work Link as a `toggle`**

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FGOSUXX5HUOG

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><a href="https://www.w3schools.com" id="w3s">W3Schools.com</a></p>

<button>Change URL</button>

<p>Mouse over the link (or click on it) to see that the value of the href attribute has changed.</p>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){
    
      var myURL = "https://www.w3schools.com";
      if( $("#w3s").attr("href") === myURL )
        $("#w3s").attr("href", "https://www.w3schools.com/jquery");
      else
        $("#w3s").attr("href", myURL);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes it's work fine... I checked.. but who gives you down vote. Wait.. I give you one up vote from my side :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a basic if-else and check the `href` attribute.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      var w3schoolURL = "https://www.w3schools.com";
      if( $("#w3s").attr("href") === w3schoolURL )
        $("#w3s").attr("href", "https://www.w3schools.com/jquery");
      else
        $("#w3s").attr("href", w3schoolURL);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p><a href="https://www.w3schools.com" id="w3s">W3Schools.com</a></p>

<button>Change href Value</button>

<p>Mouse over the link (or click on it) to see that the value of the href attribute has changed.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why the down-votes? This is the only correct answer as of now.

Comment: @Roxy'Pro Yes it works fine. You can run the snippet and confirm, there was never an issue with my answer.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it, I have no clue why answer was immediately given two down-votes after posting. Considering it was the only one that had a correct answer at the time.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var w3 = "https://www.w3schools.com";
 var w3Jquery = "https://www.w3schools.com/jquery";
 var toggleFlag = true;
    $("button").click(function(){
        if(toggleFlag){
         $("#w3s").attr("href", w3Jquery);
        }
        else{
         $("#w3s").attr("href", w3); 
        }
        toggleFlag = !toggleFlag;
    });
});
</script>

<body>
<p><a href="https://www.w3schools.com" id="w3s">W3Schools.com</a></p>

<button>Change href Value</button>

<p>Mouse over the link (or click on it) to see that the value of the href attribute has changed.</p>

</body>
```